# Inserting elements in the list using for-loop and expand the first five items

Tags: python

```
list_1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

how can i get the above list in the form of below list (repeatation needed for first 5 elements only)

```
list_1 =[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list_1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for index in range(0, 10, 2):
    list_1.insert(index, list_1[index])

print(list_1)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since good answers have been given here is a one line way to do this

```
import itertools
list_1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_list = [val for pair in itertools.zip_longest(list_1,list_1[:5],fillvalue='-' for val in pair if val != '-']
print(new_list)
```

output [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]